# C++ Converting wstring with Unicode characters to lower

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, wstring

I want to convert a wstring to lower case.

"Ärger" should be converted to "ärger".

I have not found any solution that would work without locales.
Any programming language can do that, execpt C++, I think.

Do I really have to do all the work myself by providing a map?
I was thinking that there might be a simply function to do that for me.

I am using wstrings, and the compiler is set to "Use Unicode".

Thank you.

Comment: Any significant work in Unicode is likely to need a third party Unicode library. C++ itself has no support for Unicode at all.

Comment: Just because you are using e.g. `std::wstring` or `wchar_t` doesn't mean you are using Unicode. Also, the standard "ctype" functions `towlower`  etc. are pretty naive when it comes to different encodings. You might want to look into the [ICU library](http://site.icu-project.org/) for better Unicode support.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thank you. This lib is really interesting.